# Add JavaDocs Netbeans 7.2 Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, netbeans, javadoc, netbeans-7, netbeans-7.2

A very stupid and common question . How to add javadocs of Hibernate(3.2.5) to Netbeans 7.2 . 
1) Download Link of java doc for Hibernate . 
2) Is this the correct step --- Project Properties >> Libraries >> Hibernate >> Edit >> Select ed hibernate 3 jar >> javadocs tab >> added my file . (But nothing happened)

**Please tell me help i have tried a lot but none of link worked**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Edit-Window (as you did before) select **`Javadoc --> Add URL`** and insert this one: `http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/`

Does this work?

**Please see the last few comments if this solution doesn't work for you**

Comment: Did you use the build in Hibernate or created a new Hibernate library? Btw. test both: `Hibernate` and `Hibernate API`.

Comment: If you `Project Properties -> Libraries -> Add Libraray` you see Hibernate two times: one named `Hibernate` and second one `Hibernate API`. Wich one did you use?

Comment: Strange ... added the jboss link only to Hibernate JPA and this works for both (and vice versa)

Comment: I use many other libraries in this way. But i must confess that Hibernate was realy a problem since the Javadoc from Hibernate website is note the required one - had to search the proper one first because even the downloaded doc didn't work. However, good that it works now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for anyone else having this problem but using maven to manage the dependencies, try the following:

```
mvn dependency:sources
mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc
```

The first command will attempt to download source code for each of the dependencies in your pom file.

The second command will attempt to download the Javadocs.

Comment: You type it into the command line, assuming you have maven installed and on your path.